# Protecting my source code inside android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want protect some files inside my project source code so if I sent source code to anyone he can only read the specific files and the protected ones can't read it without something like password or something else

I need to send all the project source code to someone and he can edit it and build the application normally but prevent him from access or read  specific

I am not sure if there is something do that so if someone know is that possible please answer me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This comes up sometimes with keys and other sensitive files. What we do in cases like these is to have separate development/test/production keys or files and the developer has only access to a repository with the developer keys or files. Then on merge we merge in a way which means the final build will contain the production files the developer has no access to.

If you want to defend source code parts you can use obfuscation. This will still make the build work but it only makes the code harder to understand, not that it is unavailable. Note that if the developer wants to build the project locally it needs to access all the files the build will need, and that means read access.